# How to select all column vecotrs with euclidean distance greater than some value with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

My task is to select all column vectors from a given matrix `D` which have greater value of their euclidean distance than the average euclidean distance of all the vectors from a matrix.

This is the matrix(array) `D`:

```
>>> D
array([[-1,  0,  5,  0, -1,  2,  2, -2, -1,  0],
       [ 3, -4,  4, -5, -2, -3,  1, -5, -3, -1]])
```

I've already wrote a function that computes the average euclid. distance of all the vectors:

```
import numpy as np

def average_euclid_dist (X, Y):
    return np.sum(np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)) / X.shape[0]

average_ed = average_euclid_dist(D[0,:], D(1,:))
```

And now I'm stuck figuring out how to compare each vector (column) so that only those with euc. dist greater that `average_ed` will get selected. This should be the desired output:

```
array([[ 0,  5,  0, -2],
       [-4,  4, -5, -5]])
```

I'd be glad if I didn't have to use for loop for this, preferably some numpy way how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use masks :

```
import numpy as np

D = np.array([[-1,  0,  5,  0, -1,  2,  2, -2, -1,  0], [ 3, -4,  4, -5, -2, -3,  1, -5, -3, -1]])

euclid = np.sqrt(D[0, :]**2 + D[1, :]**2) ## calculate the norm of the vectors
mask = euclid > euclid.mean() ## find the ones that are greated than the mean.
print(mask)
# [False  True  True  True False False False  True False False]

Wanted = np.array([D[0, mask],  D[1, mask]]) #Apply the mask

print((np.sqrt(Wanted[0, :]**2 + Wanted[1, :]**2) > euclid.mean()).all() ) #Verif
# True
```